# Why does the row method work in finding basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S=\left\{
u_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}
u_2=\begin{pmatrix}3\\6\\6\\3\end{pmatrix}
u_3=\begin{pmatrix}4\\9\\9\\5\end{pmatrix}
u_4=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}
u_5=\begin{pmatrix}5\\8\\9\\4\end{pmatrix}
u_6=\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\\7\\3\end{pmatrix}
\right\}$ and $V=span(S)$

$A = (u_1,u_2,...u_6)$

$A =\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 4 & -2 & 5 & 4\\
2 & 6 & 9 & -1 & 8 & 2\\
2 & 6 & 9 & -1 & 9 & 7\\
1 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 3\\
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 0 & -14 & 0 & -37\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Hence, basis for V using the column space method is $V=Col(A)$ is $\{u_1,u_3,u_5\}$. Up to this part I can understand because linear relationships between columns are preserved after performing row operations. But I do not understand the following method.

$A^T=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
3 & 6 & 6 & 3\\
4 & 9 & 9 & 5\\
-2 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
5 & 8 & 9 & 4\\
4 & 2 & 7 & 3\\
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Then $\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$ form a basis for V

Why does the row space of the transpose of A form the basis for V?

Also it is noted that this method also make it easier to write any vector in V relative to this basis.

For example, $u_6 = 
4\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}+
2\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+
7\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$

Why does it work?

Comment: Your first method does not give a basis for V - there is no way of getting a non-zero fourth component for example. The second method simply eliminates any linearly dependent rows (vectors in S) and leaves a set of linearly independent rows (a basis for V).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, the first method works because the row operations do not change the linear relations between the columns, and since the column space of RREF(A) has a basis of columns containing pivot entries, those columns in the original matrix still form a basis for the column space of A.

The second approach works under a different idea: row operations do not change the row space of a matrix.  You can check for each operation.  For example, if $v=v_1 + v_2$ and we replace $v_2$ with $v_3=v_2 + 3v_1$, then $v=-2v_1 + v_3$. So, at the end of doing Gaussian elimination, our rows span the same space, but the non-zero ones are linearly independent.  Now, just notice that taking transposes swaps row space and column space.

Comment: Thank you. I can see now why the row space also form a basis for V. But why does it make it easier to write any vector in V relative to this basis? Lets call the basis obtained from row space as T, u6_(T) = (4,2,7)

Comment: @LinnHtetAung Because when you reduce to RREF, the pivots will be the only non-zero entries in their columns, and so by looking only at those slots you can simply read off how to express something as a linear combination (if it is possible). It’s the same reason it is easy to write things in terms of the standard basis, e.g., $(2,3)=2(1,0)+3(0,1)$.

Comment: Ah. I see. I got it. Thanks a lot.